# Always open in readability mode

Tags: browser-addons, readability

Is there any add on or extensions for chrome or firefox, that will always open some sites (saved by user) in readablility (or text) mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found this extension for chrome. Save the address of the site you want to visit in readability mode, then it will always be opened in readable or text only mode

[Speedability extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ipddjephmcmophjecjilojnngnjncpdi)